# printing a value of map which has two string as key and vector as value

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, vector, io

I have a map which has two string as key and one vector as value
how can i print the value of map.

Below is my approach which is bad Can Someone help me thanks in advance

**NOTE : i want to print by key not iterating on vector**

```
int main()
{
        vector<string>value;
        std::map<std::pair<string,string> ,vector<string>> myMap;
        string input1,input2,MyvectorValue;
        for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
        {
                cin>>input1;
                cin>>input2;
                cin>>MyvectorValue;
                myMap[std::make_pair(input1,input2)].push_back(MyvectorValue);
        }
        int j=0;
        for( auto it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it )
        {
                std::vector<std::string>& value = it->second.at(j++);
               cout<<value  // This is bad

           //how can i print all map value ??
        }
}
```

Comment: why not iterating the vector and printing each value?

Comment: You keep saying you don't want to iterate the vector but how do you expect to get the values if you don't? You'll need to be more specific about your, perhaps impossible, use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the map is a vector, assuming you can use C++11, the following code would do what you need.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::string >value;
    std::map< std::pair<std::string , std::string> ,    std::vector<std::string> > myMap;
    std::string input1,input2,MyvectorValue;
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
    {

        std::cin>>input1;
        std::cin>>input2;
        std::cin>>MyvectorValue;
        myMap[std::make_pair(input1,input2)].push_back(MyvectorValue);
    }

    //If you have a particular key (string1, string2), and want to print the values for that specific key...
    auto particularKey = std::make_pair("stringA", "stringB");
    for(auto val : myMap[particularKey])
        std::cout << val << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // If you want to iterate through all keys of your map
    for(auto &elem : myMap)
    {
        std::cout << "for the pair with key (" << elem.first.first << "," << elem.first.second << "), the value is the following vector" << std::endl;
        for(auto s : elem.second)
        {
            std::cout << s << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please how can i print using key rather than iterating on vector since i do have some usecase.

Comment: The value of your map is a vector of strings, you will necessarily have to iterate through the vector of strings, to print the strings one by one.

Comment: It seems op want to print on particular key.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the keys by accessing the pair and then using `first` and `second` to get the first and second member of the pair respectively.

You can also print the values, by accessing the vectors and iterating over them, printing every string separately.

```
for(auto& element : myMap)
{
    std::cout << "Key: {" << element.first.first << ", " << element.first.second << "}\n";
    std::cout << "Value is a vector with the following strings: \n";
    for(auto& str: element.second)
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: i want to print by key not iterating on vector i ahve upate my question

Comment: @user7953556 I updated my answer, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you **want to print by key not iterating on vector** , then you may declare map as "**std::map,string> myMap**". Then, you can do following modification to your code as given below.

```
int main() {
vector<string>value;
std::map<std::pair<string,string>,string> myMap;
string input1,input2,MyvectorValue;
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) {

    cin>>input1;
    cin>>input2;
    cin>>MyvectorValue;
    myMap[std::make_pair(input1,input2)]+=MyvectorValue;
    myMap[std::make_pair(input1,input2)]+= " ";
}
for( auto it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it ) {
    std::string& value = it->second;
    cout<<value<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: you have used one string but my question was vector<string> as value

Comment: I'm sorry but, If you want to print vector, i think there is probably no other way than iterating over it.

Comment: you can check on the above accept value for your reference